# DB foreign key validation in Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, attributes, foreign-key-relationship

I need simple model attribute validation.
Lets say, I have such field:

```
public class PersonDTO
{
    public int? GenderId { get; set; }
}
```

I need clean way to validate GenderId knowing that GenderId is a foreign key for Person, 
table from Database:

```
Gender
GenderID GenderName
```

What I thought about:

```
[Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "GenderId is out of range")]
public int? GenderId { get; set; }
```

Where 1 and 10 are supposed to be lower and upper values for GenderId. It's not an option.

I thought about custom validator, which selects all GenderID's from DB and just looks if desired is in there. It's better way, but as simple as I want it to be.
I have 5 field which need similar validation.

Maybe there are built in ways I am not aware of?
Thank you.

PS. I am using Entity Framework for DB access.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, you're better off just doing manual validation in your POST action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(PersonDTO model)
{
    var gender = db.GenderIDs.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == model.GenderID);
    if (gender == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("GenderID", "That is not a valid id");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
```

Comment: I did not mention, MVC API controller receives DTO object.
And adding such validation to controller or somewhere else to check this constraint on each request will add complexity and unnecessary work to database. Maybe there are some better ways

Comment: I was aware, but I guess my code was a little confusing. I've updated it so it's more explicit.

Comment: The problem you have is that validation of this requires database access, which is not appropriate to add into the DTO class itself. If you just need to reuse the code above on multiple actions, you might look into creating a custom action filter (see: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609(v=vs.100).aspx)